# Java ASCII art using for loops

Tags: java, loops

I am completely stuck on this java loops ASCII problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLe5h.jpg

I figured out how to do the top line, but am stuck on the body. I am not sure what to put in the nested for loop in order to draw the backslashes. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
    public static void SlashFigure(int size) {  
    System.out.println();  // line break  

    for(int i = 1; i <= (size * 4 - 2); i++) {       // draw top line  
        System.out.print("!");  
    }


    for(int i = 1; i <= size - 1; i++) {            // draw body  

        for(int j = 1; j <=  ; i++){               // draw backslashes 
            System.out.println("\\");  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: Does `System.out.println("\\");` not draw backslashes?  What specifically is the problem here?

Comment: Sorry, the original question didn't post the image of the question.

Comment: `for(int j = 1; j <=  ; i++){` ?? shouldn't `j` be compared to something?  Also, why are you incrementing `i` here?  Shouldn't that be `j`?

Comment: @DanH.: Ok, you've included the homework problem.  But in what way is your attempt not working?  What is your current output?  What did you expect that output to be?  When you step through the code in a debugger, what isn't working?  Break the overall homework problem down into small pieces and try to implement them, where specifically do you get stuck?

Comment: @David I'm trying to print backslashes on every line of the figure (and obviously the number of them change with each sequential line. I am lost as far as what to write in the nested for loop to print the correct number of backslashes in each line.

Comment: @DanH.: Looks like some numbers regarding the pattern are... The main loop would go from `0` to `n-1`.  The number of slashes at the start or end of each line would be `i * 2` where `i` is the iteration of the main loop.  The total number of characters on each line would be `(n - 1) * 2 + 2`.

Comment: Since its clearly homework, I wouldn't want to give the code to you but what you need to do is keep track of number of rows and columns given number `n`. Clearly there are `n` rows and `(n*4)-2` columns. Say your rows start with index `0` so for `n=4` you would have `0,1,2,3` row numbers. Lets call this `rn`. For every row you would have `rn*4` number of backslashes. Split those so that equal number of backslashes are at the beginning and end of row. Remaining would be `!`.

Comment: @David I tried i*2 (where j <= i*2) yesterday and it printed backslahes until the I got a runtime error. Do you know why that would be?

Comment: @DanH.: Not without seeing the code, no.  It would also help you to examine what the error was telling you, as well as stepping through the code in a debugger to see what's happening and why.

Comment: @David the code is just what is in the question and on the draw backslashes line I used j <= i * 2

Comment: @DanH.: The code in the question has a syntax error and doesn't compile.  Is that the error you were talking about?  That would be a compilation error, not a runtime error.  Even if you correct the syntax error, it looks like the inner loop will continue indefinitely because you never modify the value of `j`.

Answer (score 0):

See if the following helps. Let me know if you do not understand how a certain part works in the following code.

```
    int n = 6;//given size
    int i, j, k, l;
    //for(i=0;i<2*n-1;i+=2) {
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(k=0;k<i;k++) {
            System.out.print("\\\\");
        }
        for(l=0;l<2*n-1-2*i;l++) {
            System.out.print("!!");
        }
        for(k=0;k<i;k++) {
            System.out.print("\\\\");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: I'm using a parameter in the main method to define size. I also only want to print one of each character in the loop and then use the loop to state how many times I want it to print (just how my professor wants it).

Comment: @DanH. the variable n is the size you are talking about. Just run this snippet and see how it works the way you have described.

Comment: what did you write on the second nested for loop? How did you get l<2*n-1-2*i

Comment: @DanH. it's the math I came up with based on the diagram you have shown.  Does it not make sense?